# Set an Attribute to the HeaderRow of the Radgrid [telerik] from Code Behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I have a Radgrid like this in my ASPX page,

```
   <telerik:RadGrid ID="rGVResults">
          <MasterTableView AllowPaging="false" CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0"  AllowFilteringByColumn="true" 
                            AllowSorting="true" AllowNaturalSort="false" Width="100%"
                            TableLayout="Auto" Frame="Void" GroupLoadMode="Client">              
          <Columns>
           .
           .
          </Columns>                
          </MasterTableView>
  </telerik:RadGrid>
```

Now I want to add an attribute to the header row of the radgrid from codebehind(aspx.cs) by doing this,

```
rGVResults.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Attributes["data-class"] = "expand";
```

Which works fine for an asp:gridview but not with the telerik radgrid.
What am I doing wrong?

Can someone suggest me an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
rGVResults.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Attributes.Add("data-class", "expand");
```

Or try this way

```
 protected void RadGrid1_ItemCreated(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)  
{  
    if (e.Item is GridDataItem)  
    {  
        GridDataItem dataItem = e.Item as GridDataItem;  
        TableCell cell = dataItem["ColumnUniqueName"];  
        cell.Attributes["data-class"] = "expand";  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Tried that. Gets an error message saying

'Telerik.Web.UI.RadGrid' does not contain a definition for 'HeaderRow' and no extension method 'HeaderRow' accepting a first argument of type 'Telerik.Web.UI.RadGrid' could be found

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
rGVResults.HeaderStyle.CssClass = "expand";
```

The default value is System.String.Empty.